# Javax-mail with multithread

Tags: java, imap, smpp, jakarta-mail

I am working on a java application which takes and saves all mails with attachemnts.But i want to do it multithread.My idea is like that.

One timer thread is getting all mails and put them in a BlockingQueue.I am putting `Javax.mail.Message` object to the queue.Then my worker threads are taking and processing them.

Problem is that when worker threads are taking Message and calling the methods:

```
Message.getFolder.open();

Message.getFolder.close();
```

causes problems.If one thread opens the folder and another one try to open same folder, application is throwing **Operation is not allowed** exception.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: According to me you should have either one reader thread or One Folder per thread. This will resolve your problem. Don't try to read same folder with same thread. Or alternatively you can get Message from one folder once your main thread has open your folder for read operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Folder.isOpen() - Indicates whether this Folder is in the 'open' state.` before opening it, like

```
Folder folder = Message.getFolder();

if(folder.isOpen()==false){
folder.open();
}
```

Similarly before closing, check if it already open then only close:

```
  if(folder.isOpen()){
    folder.close();
  }
```